# Inline referencing chapters, sections, subsections, etc

Tags: publications, thesis, writing-style

I am currently in the process of writing my Master's thesis using the LaTeX class supplied by my university. This class uses a document structure similar to `report`: Starting with chapters, then sections, then subsections and so on. Citation style is IEEE, if that's important.

What is the correct way to reference all these text-divisions within my flow-text, especially when reaching `\subsection{}` level and below?

Example A

> As shown in chapter "Foo" and section "Bar", [...].
>
> [...], for further details see subsection "Baz" and subsubsubsection "Qux".

or Example B

> As shown in section "Foo" and section "Bar", [...].
>
> [...], for further details see section "Baz" and section "Qux".

or something completely different?

Answer (score 0):

You can use command `label`, e.g.,

> \section{My Section}\label{section:MySection}
>
> \subsection{My Subsection}\label{section:MySubsection}

Then you can use:

> ...Sections~\ref{section:MySection} and \ref{section:MySubsection}...